# Unable to extract PyCharm file: 'Archive type not supported' on Linux Mint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, linux-mint

I've recently been trying out programming on Linux Mint Tessa, and so far it hasn't been going great. I've downloaded the PyCharm IDE file and have tried numerous times to extract it, but it doesn't work! When I navigate to my downloads folder and look at the PyCharm file, it shows a locked sign over the box icon. When I try and right click it and extract it, it says: Could  not open "pycharm community-2018.3.3.tar-1": archive type not supported. Can anybody help? Please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download the archive from an official site, it should be `.tar.gz` extension.

You can unarchive it using terminal

`tar -xvzf pycharm-community-2018.3.3.tar.gz`

this video can help https://youtu.be/WM1bzV9S0kQ

Comment: Thanks, but I already fixed it. I tried this in the past, but it didn't work. I just uninstalled and reinstalled PyCharm and now it works like a charm. Thanks anyway, though!